# Error when trying to debug in WebStorm: “Must be absolute path”

Tags: webstorm

I get the above error when I try to using debugger in WebStorm.

Any help?

Comment: please share a screenshot of your run configuration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happened to me recently and almost drove me insane. The problem was a breakpoint in a dynamically generated script that no longer existed. After clearing all breakpoints the issue disappeared.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly the issue for us.